# Conditionally formatting if multiple cells are blank (no numerics throughout spreadsheet )

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have created a spreadsheet in Excel and am attempting to use Conditional Formatting to highlight a cell or row if any or all of the cells in the last four columns are blank.  My columns consist of name of `account`, `store manager`, `city`, `state`, `visit 1`, `visit 2`, `visit 3` and `visit 4`.

When an account is visited notes are written in the "Visit" cell and if an account does not need a visit an `X` is put in each "Visit" column that is not needed (some accounts need one visit, some two, some all four).

Is it possible to have the Account Name and/or Manager Name highlighted when any visits are left blank, indicating they need to set up a visit that is necessary?

I have tried the instructions below but it didn't seem to work for the range of information I was looking for.

---

1. Open the 'Conditional Formatting Rules Manager' (Conditional
   Formatting->Manage Rules).
2. Click 'New Rule' and choose "Use a formula to determine which cells
   to format".
3. In the "Format values where this formula is true:" box, enter the
   cell which you want to check if blank.
4. Place a dollar sign in front of the letter of the cell reference to
   make it affect only that row, not the whole table or just the cell.
5. Type ="" at the end of the box to check for if the cell is blank.
6. Click "Format..." and go to the "Fill" tab to choose a colour to
   fill the row if true and click "OK".
7. Click "Okay" to close the 'New Rule' dialog.
8. Change the "Applies to" value of the rule you just created to the
   scope of the entire table to make the rule apply to it. (If your
   table has a reference name, you can enter it here)
9. Click "Okay to close the 'Conditional Formatting Rules Manager'.

Comment: `=IF(LEN(E3)*LEN(F3)*LEN(G3)*LEN(H3)=0,1,0)` a simple formula to identify if any cell is blank assuming E2, F2, G2, H2 contain the visit.s

Answer (score 12):

[image]

How about just > Format only cells that contain  - in the drop down box select Blanks

Comment: Maybe not an answer to original question, but this helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Select columns A:H with A1 as the active cell.
2. Open Home ► Styles ► [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) ► New Rule.
3. Choose **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** and supply one of the following formulas¹ in the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box.

   - To highlight the Account and Store Manager columns when one of the four dates is blank:
             `=AND(LEN($A1), COLUMN()<3, COUNTBLANK($E1:$H1))`
   - To highlight the Account, Store Manager and blank date columns when one of the four dates is blank:
             `=AND(LEN($A1), OR(COLUMN()<3, AND(COLUMN()>4, COUNTBLANK(A1))), COUNTBLANK($E1:$H1))`
4. Click [Format] and select a cell Fill.
5. Click [OK] to accept the formatting and then [OK] again to create the new rule. In both cases, the **Applies to:** will refer to `=$A:$H`.

Results should be similar to the following.

[image: Conditionally formatting if multiple cells are blank]

---

¹ <sub>The [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-6a92d772-675c-4bee-b346-24af6bd3ac22) was introduced with Excel 2007. It will count both true blanks and zero-length strings left by formulas (e.g. `""`).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The steps you took are not appropriate because the cell you want formatted is not the trigger cell (presumably won't normally be blank). In your case you want formatting to apply to one set of cells according to the status of various *other* cells. I suggest with data layout as shown in the image (and with thanks to @xQbert for a start on a suitable formula) you select ColumnA and:

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(LEN(E1)*LEN(F1)*LEN(G1)*LEN(H1)=0,NOT(ISBLANK(A1)))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting, OK, OK.

[image: SO22487695 example]

where I have filled yellow the cells that are triggering the red fill result.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the dollar sign before the letter, you will affect only the column, not the row.
If you want to have it affect only a row, place the dollar before the number.

You may want to use =isblank() rather than =""

I'm also confused by your comment "no values throughout spreadsheet - just text" - text is a value.

One more hint - excel has a habit of rewriting rules - I don't know how many rules I've written only to discover that excel has changed the values in the "apply to" or formula entry fields.

If you could post an example, I'll revise the answer.  Conditional formatting is very finicky.